# Custom @Qualifier with Spring autoconfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm not sure how to use custom qualifier interface with component scanning and autowire in Spring. I have an interface:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.PARAMETER,ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface BigBean {
}
```

a bean I want to injected to:

```
@Component
public class Bean {

   @Autowired
   @BigBean("A")
   private SomeBean sb;

   public SomeBean getSb() {
       return sb;
   }
   public void setSb(SomeBean sb) {
       this.sb = sb;
   }
}
```

and beans of the same type to be distinguished by custom qualifier:

```
@Component
@BigBean("A") //<-????
public class SmallBeanA implements SomeBean{
}

@Component
public class SmallBeanB implements SomeBean{
}
```

What I found in [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-qualifiers) doesn't compile in my case. How to use this custom qualifier I have?

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the compilation error you get.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to add attribute value to BigBean annotation as

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.PARAMETER,ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface BigBean {

    String value() default "";
}
```

Comment: Ok, that fixed compiler error in Bean, now how to use this qualifier to actually point to one instance? How should I mark SmallBeanA?

Comment: Did you use the correct `@Qualifier` annotation if that is the case your code should work.

Comment: I used:import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier; I don't believe it should work, I doesn't even compile with error in SmallBeanA

Comment: In Bean class modify                                                                           `@Autowired
 @Qualifier("A")
 private Bean bean;`

Comment: let me clarify: I want to inject a selected instance of SomeBean (one of two avaliable) not a Bean

Comment: Yes that's a typo, it should be Somebean sb;

Answer (score 1):

This a bit old thread now, not sure if my answer will be of any help or not but let me try. Below is code to inject a selected instance of SomeBean.

---

```
@Qualifier
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BigBean {
    String value() default "";
}


public interface SomeBean { 
}


@Component
@BigBean("A")
public class SmallBeanA implements SomeBean {
    private SmallBeanA() {
        System.out.println("SmallBeanA constructed");
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SmallBeanA";
    }
}


@Component
@BigBean("B")
public class SmallBeanB implements SomeBean{
    private SmallBeanB() {
        System.out.println("SmallBeanB constructed");
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SmallBeanB";
    }
}


@Component
public class Bean {
    @Autowired
    @BigBean("A")
    private SomeBean sb;
    public SomeBean getSb() {
        return sb;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bean [sb=" + sb + "]";
    }
}



public class QualifierTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
        Bean myBean = context.getBean(Bean.class);
        System.out.println(myBean.getSb().toString());
        //OR
        System.out.println(myBean.toString());
    }
}
```